# CSS 100% Height with many Nested and Floated Divs

Tags: css, html, height, css-float

I am working on a layout consisting of several nested Divs and I am ideally looking to get the content areas to stretch the height of the screen.  This is pretty simple and I have done it in the past but not in this type of layout and am struggling with it.  Instead of me pasting all of the code, I uploaded it to server that can be previewed.

http://www.danyuschick.com/theembalmed/

Any help would be great.  I'm at my wit's end with this right now.

Comment: what exactly you want, it's not clear from the source that you have provided.

Comment: So many nested divs often end up causing problems and complicating debugging, not to mention unnecessarily bloating code. I recommend you make your layout much, much simpler. Using `float` for layout can be a bad practice, as well. As punit said, it's also not clear exactly how you want it, so you could give more detail for us to help you.

Comment: I am looking to have the border lines stretch from top to bottom as well as the content div.  I acknowledge this is more divs than I normally and prefer to use but I'm not too sure how else to achieve the design I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property

> < percentage >
>
> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, **the value computes to 'auto'**.

So whenever you use percentages as height the containing block of the element must have an explicit height to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link:

http://ninja-code.net/extra/stackoverflow_test.php

It uses a lot less DIV and will expand as you fill content. It also keeps your images as borders along the 'conent' - I wasn't sure if you were wanting it to repeat.

I didn't want to hassle with pushing the footer to the bottom though.